# MIME RSA encryption

Tags: encryption, openssl, mime-types

i have this scheme[image]

how can i use session-key in MIME to encrypt the message?

i used this command but i don't think it is correct

```
openssl enc -e -des3 -salt -in MSg_sign.txt -out session.txt
```

can you tell me the command to encrypt MIME using session-key